# How to get the result based on string matched with array in php?

Tags: php

I have an array from which i need to print if phone number is matched with string and to show the first name based on that number? i have to print the corresponding number with name. how to achieve that

```
$phone_number = 8056006655;

   Array ( [0] => Array ( [phone] => 8056006655 [country_code] => +91 [status] => [email] => +918056006655@sugaldamanifoundations.com [call_groups] => Array ( ) [role] => [wrap_up_times] => Array ( ) [first_name] => Dominic [id] => 850688 [opt_in] => 1 [last_name] => )
```

Comment: What PHP version?

Comment: @Doug i m using 5.6

Comment: foreach($get_agent_array['objects'] as $key=>$value){
         
     $agent_phone_number['phone_number'] = $value['phone'];
     $agent_first_name['first_name'] = $value['first_name'];
     
     //print_r(array_merge($agent_phone_number['phone_number'],$agent_first_name['first_name']));
     
   //echo $get_agent_array['objects'][$key]['phone'];  
   //print_r($agent_phone_number['phone_number']);
   
    }

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for it's array_column within an array_search, prior to php. 5.5 you would need an ugly foreach, however from 5.5 you can use something like below.

```
$phone_number = 8056006655;

$array = array(
    [0] => Array (
        [phone] => 8056006655 
        [country_code] => +91
        [status] => 
        [email] => +918056006655@sugaldamanifoundations.com
        [call_groups] => Array ( ) 
        [role] => 
        [wrap_up_times] => Array ( )  
        [first_name] => Dominic
        [id] => 850688 
        [opt_in] => 1
        [last_name] =>
        )
 );


 $key = array_search($phone_number,     
            array_column($array, 'phone')
         );

echo $array[$key]['first_name'];
```

Comment: i have to print the firstname based on the phone number

Comment: how to combine phone and country

Comment: Where is your data coming from in the first place?

Comment: array_column alternate